# Passing self reference to from a generic class

Tags: cocoa, swift

I'd like to know how to pass `self` reference from a generic class. In other words, how can I get rid of `AnyObject` in the following code?

```
protocol StateControllerDelegate: class {

    typealias StateType

    func stateController(stateController: AnyObject, didTransitionFromState fromState: StateType, toState: StateType)

}

class StateController<StateControllerDelegateType: StateControllerDelegate> {

    var delegate: StateControllerDelegateType?

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you use StateControllerDelegate instead of AnyObject in the delegate function? Or you want the type of the which extends the protocol?

Comment: I tried. Compiler complains that it requires arguments in <...>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
protocol StateControllerDelegate: class {

    typealias StateType

    func stateController(stateController: StateController<Self>, didTransitionFromState fromState: StateType, toState: StateType)

    var fromState: StateType { get }
    var   toState: StateType { get }
}

class StateController<StateControllerDelegateType: StateControllerDelegate> {

    var delegate: StateControllerDelegateType?

    func callDelegate() {
        delegate!.stateController(self,
            didTransitionFromState: delegate!.fromState,
                           toState: delegate!.toState)
    }
}

final class MyDelegate: StateControllerDelegate {

    typealias StateType = Int

    func stateController(stateController: StateController<MyDelegate>, didTransitionFromState fromState: StateType, toState: StateType) {
        println("fromState=\(fromState), toState=\(toState)")
    }

    var fromState: StateType { return 0; }
    var   toState: StateType { return 1; }
}


let ctrl = StateController<MyDelegate>()
ctrl.delegate = MyDelegate()
ctrl.callDelegate()
```

**EDIT**; I would like to leave an explanation for the important point.

I made the `MyDelegate` as a `final` class because, if I don't, `StateController<Self>` in the context of `MyDelegate` means `StateController<T>` (where `T` can be any type which inherits `MyDelegate`), so `StateController<MyDelegate>` in the function signature does not conform to `StateController<Self>`. At the moment, Swift doesn't support any covariance/contravariance-like feature, so making `StateController<Y>` compatible to `StateController<X>` (where `Y` extends `X`) is impossible. But once I add `final` to the class `MyDelegate`, now `StateController<Self>` means just `StateController<MyDelegate>` (in the context of `MyDelegate`).

Comment: Very interesting. Looks great. Why did you add `fromState` and `toState` properties? I left them out and got no compiler errors.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic It's just for demonstration. To get `callDelegate` working, I had to pass values of the `StateType` to the delegate method, getting these from somewhere knowing a concrete type of `StateType`. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Your English is excellent. Here's the result of your help: https://github.com/salutis/StateController